# Display properties of Model based on one Model property

Tags: c#, validation, razor

I have a clientModel :

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public AddSpecificitiesViewModel dep {get; set;}
    public AddSpecificitiesViewModel dest {get; set;}
}
```

The AddSpecificitiesViewModel is as follows:

```
 public class AddSpecificitiesViewModel
 {
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
 }
```

On loading the screen, the action, Index of my ClientController is hit:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
       ClientViewModel client = new ClientViewModel();
       client.Type = "Des";
       if (client.Type == "Des"){
            //Config function create a new AddSpecificitiesViewModel with the correct values
            Config(dep)
            client.dest = null;
       } else if (client.Type == "Dest"){
            Config(dest)
            client.dep = null;
       }
   }
```

In my view, I have the followind fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Client"}))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOfService)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TypeOfService)
    </div>
    <h3>Departure</h3>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dep.Country)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dep.Country, Model.dep.CountryList, "")
    </div>
    <h3>Destination</h3>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dest.Country)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dest.Country, Model.dest.CountryList, "")
    </div>  
}
```

So how can I display only the Departure part or Destination part based on the value Type of ClientViewModel.

And how do I go with validation using fluent validation?
I have done something like this for fluent validation:

```
RuleFor(obj => obj.dest).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(typeof(BStrings),  "Error").Unless(obj => obj.Type == "Dest" || obj.TypeOfService == "Other");
RuleFor(obj => obj.dep).NotNull().WithLocalizedMessage(typeof(BStrings), "Error").Unless(obj => obj.Type == "Dep" || obj.TypeOfService == "Other");
```

Comment: why not just check if one of them is `null` ?

Comment: @Infinity : There will be cases where both will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if statements to render only what you want:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Client"}))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOfService)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TypeOfService)
    </div>
    @if (model.Type == "DES")
    {
        <h3>Departure</h3>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dep.Country)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dep.Country, Model.dep.CountryList, "")
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <h3>Destination</h3>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dest.Country)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dest.Country, Model.dest.CountryList, "")
        </div>  
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we doing something with show/hide?  Cause in the case I need to display both dep and dest,  I will have to repeat the code.  Maybe a javascript on load which will display different fields.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
    @if (Model.Type.ToUpper().Equals("DES") && Model.dep!=null)
        {
            <h3>Departure</h3>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dep.Country)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dep.Country, Model.dep.CountryList, "")
            </div>
        }

   @if(Model.Type.ToUpper().Equals("DEST") && Model.dest!=null)
        {
            <h3>Destination</h3>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dest.Country)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dest.Country, Model.dest.CountryList, "")
            </div>  
        }
```